# Unreal Engine 4: Character collider goes through floor when crouching

Tags: collision, game-physics, unreal-engine4

I'm using the 3rd person blueprint template and I've added a custom sprint and custom crouch functionality to it.. when crouching I trigger the crouching animations according to the character speed and set the max walk speed to a low value, I can interrupt the crouch by sprinting and vice versa... I can stand up from the crouch by pressing the crouch key again or attempting to jump.

It all worked quite well, until I attempted to manipulate the capsule collider's half height according to the character's speed whenever crouch, jump, or sprint is pressed... I can see the collider working as expected, however when I try to crouch the character's feet sink into the ground and when I try to stand up again the character falls through the floor...

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Maybe show us a screenshot of the part where you modify the capsule height?

Comment: There it is..

http://oi58.tinypic.com/wujacm.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that just shrinking the half-height is probably not what you want when your character is crouching, because your collision capsule is shrinking from the top and the bottom.

[image: Full capsule]

[image: Half capsule]

So, the feet of your character start to sink into the ground and when you grow your capsule it will clip through your level and fall down due to gravity.

You have two possibilities to fix this:

- Use two capsules on your character, one for crouching and one for standing and only activate the one you are using
- Move the capsule down the same time you are shinking it.

Comment: I tried the first option, I created a second capsule collider (crouch collider), set its half-height and radius to 0, in the character blueprint I set the capsule collider's half-height and radius to 0 when crouching then I set the crouch collider's half-height to 65 and radius to 42, and when uncrouching I set the crouch collider's half-height and radius to 0 and then set the Capsule collider's half-height to 96 and the radius to 42
Both colliders scale properly but the character sinks into the ground when crouching and back to normal when standing back up

http://i62.tinypic.com/33xvszl.jpg

Answer (score -1):

The capsule needs to finish at the same point, so move it lower.